# Read out of a csv file with python

Tags: python, html, csv

I want to read the last 24 rows of a csv file using python. So for example if the csv Data has 500 rows, I want to write row 476 to row 500. I dont know how many rows the csv file has. I tried this code, doesn't work. 
Can someone help me?

```
csvData.readlines()[-24:]
    html.write('{ x: new Date('+ row[0] + '), y:' + row[2] + '},')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
csvData.readlines()[-24:]
```

returns a list of all lines in your file. Appropriate code could be:

```
for row in csvData.readlines()[-24:]:
    html.write('{ x: new Date('+ row[0] + '), y:' + row[2] + '},')
```

Comment: Correction: not all but last 24!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a for loop to read the lines. `csvData.readlines()` returns a list of lines. So, by doing something like below you can achieve what you want:

`for row in csvData.readlines()[-n:]: # you can read the last n lines`